# iSCSI initiator - target connection timed out

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, virtualization, iscsi

I have three Virtual machines running on Workstation Pro 17 that are all on a Virtual network:

1. DNS master server
2. DHCP server (doubles as slave DNS)
3. Ubuntu Desktop client.

I have setup iSCSI on the 2nd server. I want to connect to it using the following command: **sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.1.251**

But the connection just times out. (**iscsiadm: connect to 192.168.1.251 timed out**)

Things to know;

- The machines are all on 'Host-Only' network setting in Workstation, they (3 VMs) can only talk to each other.
- The client is being given an IP from the DHCP
- All machines can ping each other and are on the same subnet.
- I restarted both machines and the iSCSI service itself.
- I have a domain that seems to be working fine.
- I have allowed port 3260 through my servers firewall (ufw)
- I have compared the names for the initiator multiple times side by
  side, they are the same.

The configs i have:

**Server:**

/etc/tgt/conf.d/target01.conf

```
backing-store /var/lib/iscsi_disks/disk01.img

initiator-name iqn.2023-05.com.calmnet:client1.initiator01

incominguser username password
```

**Client**

/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi

> InitiatorName=iqn.2023-05.com.calmnet:client1.initiator01

/etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf

line 58 : uncomment

> node.session.auth.authmethod = CHAP

line 69,70: uncomment + username & password

> node.session.auth.username = james
>
> node.session.auth.password = Password01

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks